# How to use arabert-v2 completely offline?

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I want to use the arabert-v2 preprocess offline. but it seems saving model is not enough for arabert preprocess function. What else should I download? any ideas?

The git repository:
https://github.com/aub-mind/arabert

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded the model and tokenizer with for example:

```
model_name = "aubmindlab/aragpt2-mega"
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

You can then save them locally with:

```
model.save_pretrained("../model")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("../tokenizer")
```

And you can access the model for example with:

```
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("./model")
```

Comment: it seems this is not enough. Wissam Antoun who is one of the contributors in the library answered via email:
The preprocessor for Arabert v2 and v1, uses the Farasa segmenter package which internally calls a java .jar file to do the segmentation.
In order to use the this package offline, I think you need to clone the project from here https://github.com/MagedSaeed/farasapy . Then modify the target location where the zip file containing the farasa jars to a location where you have manually already downloaded the zip file.
any idea how I should do this